# $24$ divides $a^2+23$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that $24$ divides $a^2 + 23$ if $a$ is not divisible by $2$ or $3$.

Well $a^2=8k+1$
for some $k$.

So, $$a^2+23 = (8k+1)+23=8(k+3)$$
So, $8$ divides $a^2+23$.

Now can $3$ divide $a^2+ 23$ so that in the end $24$ divides $a^2+23$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $a$ is not a multiple of $2$ or $3$, then $a=6m\pm 1$ and then
$$a^2+23=36m^2\pm12m+1+23=12(3m^2\pm m+2)$$
so it suffices to show that $3m^2\pm m$ is even. And indeed it is, because $3m^2\pm m=m(3m\pm 1)$, and one of these two factors is even.

Comment: to prove $3m^2 + m$ is even do we use $m = 2r$ and$ m=2r+1$ or we have to use $6m \pm 1$

Answer (score 1):

$a$ doesn't divide $3$ so:

$$
a\equiv\pm 1[3]\\
a^2 \equiv 1[3]\\
a^2+23 \equiv 24\equiv 0[3]
$$

So $3$ divides $a^2+23$ and since you correctly showed that $8|a^2+23$ and knowing that $\gcd(8,3)=1$ So :

$$
24|a^2+23
$$

I used the property that:

$$
a|b\quad \mathrm{and}\quad b|c \Longrightarrow \mathrm{lcm}(a,b)|c\\
ab=\gcd(a,b)\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)
$$

Answer (score 1):

$a^2+23=(a-1)(a+1)+24$

Since $a$ is odd; $a-1$ and $a+1$ are even.

Moreover, since $4$ does not divide $a$, 4 divides either $a-1$ or $a+1$.

Since $3$ does not divide $a$, $3$ divides either $a-1$ or $a+1$.

Hence $2\times 4\times 3$ divides $(a-1)(a+1)$.